# Java - Runnable

Tags: java, android, arrays, imageview

I'm trying to set an imageview's resource like so:

Code:

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.bg);
```

Yet I see nothing on my screen.

I can set

```
imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bgView);
```

And it works, but in my instance I can't use this because I need apply the imageview to an arraylist of imageviews.

Is there any other way to construct my imageview or am I doing something wrong?

Edit:

My xml looks like:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/entire_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/black"
tools:context="com.example.guilyan.Game" >


       <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bgView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:contentDescription="@string/Descript"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@+drawable/testpicks" />


</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: you aren't adding the imageView you create in the first instance to the View

Comment: Initially add any dummy image as resource of imageview ,later you can change the resource of imageview. Don't create the imageview dynamically.

Comment: I'd like to make 50 of these images though by using an arraylist, is the only way I have to make 50 imageviews in xml then? And could you explain how I add it to the View?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think u should add the dynamically created image view to your layout.just try this.Suppose if your layout id is frameLayout then

```
frameLayout.addView(imageView);
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to change my framelayout id to a ViewGroup and then it worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Using of

`new ImageView(getApplicationContext());` not correct.
You need use activity context, not application.
And of course after initialization of view you need attach it to parent.